# Из одного activity пытаюсь создать кнопку в другом

Tags: java, android, activity

у меня несколько activity, когда пользователь нажимает кнопку выполняется **метод** который должен добавить на другое activity кнопку. Затем сразу переход на ту вьюшку куда добавили кнопку, пользователь перешел и видит ее наличие. Но у меня ошибка.

```
public class AlarmClock extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

       Button alarm_on, alarm_off;
       LinearLayout selectClockView;
```

Для этого в **onCreate** был создан LinearLayot , к нему далее и обращаемся

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_clock);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    selectClockView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewSelectClock);
    //инициализация виджетов
}
```

А в методе я уже создаю кнопку и addViev на activity, но при добавлении ошибка

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParam
            = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    Button newClock = new Button(this);
    newClock.setText(hour_string + ":" + minute_string);
    newClock.setTextSize(24);
    selectClockView.addView(newClock, btnParam);
```

Почему то говорит, что нет вью, хотя я вон, создал же.
ОШИБКА

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Покажите побольше кода, ибо непонятно, что где и когда происходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во время жизни приложения может существовать только одна активити. При запуске другой первая уходит в фон и лучше всего считать, что её уже не существует. Вам надо иначе выстраивать логику. Менять разметку одной активити из другой - нельзя и не надо.

Есть разные варианты решения:

1. Запускать активити, где добавляется кнопка через `startActivityForResult` - так, при возврате на первую у вас будет вызван `onActivityResult` куда вы передадите какие-то данные, согласно коим измените разметку первой активити.
2. Во второй активити писать что-то куда-то, например в `SharedPreferences` - и при возврате к первой активити проверять в ней эти значения и соответственно менять разметку.